# How to get value inside .html() in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement an inline edit of Todo lists. I have this code and I want to be able to get the value inside it.

```
$(function clickedit() {
    $(".a").dblclick(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        var id_val = $(this).attr('value');
        //alert(id_val);

        updateVal(currentEle, value, id_val);/**/
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value, id_val) {
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" id="aaa" type="text" value="' + value + '" />'); // i want to get the value inside the input
    var aaa = $('#aaa').val();
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {



        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            alert(aaa);

            $.post('includes/edit-task3.php', { task_name: aaa, task_id:  id_val}, function() {
                $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
                alert('in');
                //current_element.parent().fadeOut("fast", function() { $(this).remove(); });
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
    });
}
```

How can I get the current value in the input inside .html()?

I tried, `var aaa = $('#aaa').val();` but it does not work.. How can I do this?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: `$(currentEle).find('#aaa').val();` try this

Comment: you do this hacked version `var aaa = value`;

Comment: @madalinivascu, Or just use `value` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put your events in a function that is triggered by something else

```
$(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
           var aaa = $(this).val();
            alert(aaa);

            $.post('includes/edit-task3.php', { task_name: aaa, task_id:  id_val}, function() {
                $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
                alert('in');
                //current_element.parent().fadeOut("fast", function() { $(this).remove(); });
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find(SELECTOR)`

```
$(currentEle).find('#aaa').val();
```

**Edit:** As `updateVal` `function` could be invoked many times, you will have multiple `ID` having same `value` in the `DOM`. Make sure the **ID must be unique**

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for that information and also for your help. Still, thank you.